# Seeking open source software for post-processing > Utility mapping?

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations, arcpad, post-processing

I am using Mobile Mapper 10 with MobileMapper Field 4.7 Mapping software more mapping of underground,cables and pipes as well as various point features. The standard accuracy is 2m, I need compatible open source post-processing software, which will allow be to get 0.5m accuracy.

Will  "GeoKettle" work? (previously recommended for MobileMapper CX).

I can also use ESRI ArcPad 7, would this allow post-processing?

If not, is there some other software which can be recommended with ArcPad 7?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you will have to rely on the GNSS device manufacturer's software to perform post-processing of field observations.
You should be able to use the Mobile Mapper Office software to do this.  I would recommend contacting the reseller who sold you the Mobile Mapper to source this software.
Here is a link where you can download the software for now.
http://mobilemapper-office.software.informer.com/

Here is a link to a YouTube video with instructions:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZbmg5T9pS8
In response to your second question:  No, ArcPad will not collect the data needed for post processing.  ArcPad just collects the positions without any of the raw data.  There are third party add-ins that will collect the raw observations but you need specific receivers and software for that.

Comment: Thanks Drew. Can you recommend third-party add-inns and receivers required? this way I can determine which would be the easiest and cost effective route to go.

Comment: To get submeter accuracy the only products I know are Trimble.  They have an extension called Trimble Positions that is an extension running inside of ArcPad and ArcGIS Desktop that allows you to collect the raw GPS measurements in the field and then correct them and check the data back into a database.